# Array in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

If I have to translate `short int v[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}` into `assembly` code how can I do it? It is ok if I'm doing something like this:

```
Enter 16,0
Mov ebp-4, 1
Mov ebp-8, 2
Mov ebp-12, 3
Mov ebp-16, 4
```

Thanks.

Comment: what assembler syntax is this? Intel syntax requires `[]` around memory references (from the operand order it looks like Intel syntax). And each assembler has subtle differences, MASM: `mov word ptr [ebp-4], 1`, NASM: `mov word [ebp-4], 1` ... and you can put the values 2 bytes apart, as `short int` is `int16_t` (probably). Also if you read those values in memory, you will end with @ebp-16 address: 4, 3, 2, 1 ... The C source was 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... So you are very close, but it's not the same, you got principle right, now tune details. Try it in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/7woqUa

Comment: hey, thank you. I wanted for NASM ;)

Comment: what about " v dw 1,2,3,4,5 " ?

Comment: @Tommylee2k that's not usable for local variable stored in stack, only for global/static in `.data`. Andreea: adding "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" to the gcc options in the previous link will force it to use `ebp` notation, closer to your original source: https://godbolt.org/g/qv35Tp  (if you are not experienced to spot how the `esp` can be exploited in the first variant, this one should be more readable to you -> but I strongly suggest to copy all the variants (including -O3 ones) into debugger, and single-step over them reasoning about their differences and how each works = will teach you a lot)

Comment: he didn't say he want's local variables ;-) tbh he didn't specify anything. we just reasoned this from his code snippet

Comment: In my first comment I just did use `word ptr` and `word`, but didn't have enough space to explain: the assembler can't tell from `mov [ebp],1` how "big" the `1` is, how many bytes in memory to overwrite, so in this case you must specify the size, for various style reasons the most logical is to specify it on the memory operand side, i.e. `mov byte [ebp],1` vs `mov dword [ebp],1`, etc... when you store register, the size is implicitly given by register used: `mov [ebp],al` vs `mov [ebp],eax`, no need to write it explicitly.  @Tommylee2k from `enter 16` and `ebp-X` = guessing, but you've point.

Comment: Write that code in C/C++ and checkout the disassembled code.

Comment: @Asesh: despite popular belief, there is no language called "C/C++".

Comment: @usr2564301 That means C or C++. Hope you will understand

Comment: @usr2564301 Even the C++ purists have in every second larger project somewhere `extern "C" { ... }` calling some C code and building that together, so.. :) (while I admit C++ is simply different language, that border line is so thin and so easy to cross). In this particular case both C and C++ would be equally relevant, they compile the native POD types in the same way, and also use the stack space for local variables in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but as @Ped7g pointed out, you need qualifiers. v[0] is going to be 20 bytes lower in memory, so you'd have to write them in reverse order.

```
        enter   20, 0

; At this point ESP is the pointer to v[]

        mov     dword [bp-20], 1
        mov     dword [bp-16], 2
        mov     dword [bp-12], 3
        mov     dword [bp-8], 4
        mov     dword [bp-4], 5
```

The reason you have to use dword's is because imagine the contest of stack as follows;

> 2F 3D 17 0A 41 FF 16 18 03 22 19 0D 01 F3 D1 0C 12 02 EE 4A

using byte qualifier for byte **[bp-4], 5** would only change 2F. DWORD however changes all 4 bytes and then becomes

> 05 00 00 00

To save program space, you could also

```
        push    bp
        mov     bp, sp
        push    5
        push    4
        push    3
        push    2
        push    1
```

There are caveats to this, but because the IA32 is structured, these will extend to 32 bits. Does use a lot less code though.

Declared outside a procedure, then it would become

```
    v:    dw    1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: You are defining `v: dd 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` on the stack. It's possible to define shorts array in stack memory, even if the default `push/pop` operates with dwords, you can still even use `push`, like `push 0x50004` `push 0x30002` `push 0x10000` to have word array at original `esp-10` with 2B junk at esp-11 and esp-12 (or new esp+0, esp+1, and array is at esp+2 to esp+11). If you would check the godbolt links from my comments, the C compiler indeed will produce short array, in stack (but by using `mov`, not `push`).